# Как задать директивы компилятору для группы проектов в Delphi 7?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Допустим у нас есть 2 группы проектов - `ProjectGroupA.bpg` и `ProjectGroupB.bpg`. Каждая группа состоит из EXE и проектов модулей bpl.

В состав каждой группы входят одинаковые проекты `Project1.bpl`, `Project2.bpl`, `Project3.bpl` и разные проекты `appA.exe`, `Project5.bpl` и `appB.exe`, `Project6.bpl`, примерно вот так: ProjectGroupA.bpg (проекты exeA-1-2-3-5) и ProjectGroupB.bpg (проекты exeB-1-2-3-6).

В общих проектах (1,2,3) есть незначительные отличия для работы в составе приложения A или B, такие, которые хорошо разруливаются директивами условной компиляции (включение некоторых строк в bpl, например).

Вопрос - Как установить директивы компиляции на уровне группы проектов, чтобы при сборке группы проектов A, ко всем модулям применялась директива `DEFINE_PROJECT_A`, а при сборке группы проектов B, ко всем модулям применялась директива `DEFINE_PROJECT_B` ?

Comment: Боюсь, что это можно будет сделать только через "кастомную" сборку всех проектов группы с использованием MSBuild... У группы проектов нет ничего "индивидуализирующего".
Ой, а тут еще и D7...там кажется даже msbuild не пойдет...

Comment: @kami я пока смотрю в сторону добавления в каждую группу ver.bpl по разным путям (типа A\ver.bpl и B\ver.bpl и юнита в их составе с константой типа `const PROJECT_ = 1`), далее во всех проектах можно указать использование этого модуля и юнита (имя то совпадет) и директивы `{$IF PROJECT_ = 1}` которая должна сработать в Делфи 7.